# Apending CSV files with columns in different orders

Tags: csv, utf-8, append, libreoffice

I need to regularly merge data from multiple CSV files into a single spreadsheet by appending the rows from each source file. Only OpenOffice/LibreOffice is able to read the UTF-8 CSV file, which has quote-delimited fields containing newline characters.

Now, each CSV file column headings, but the order of the columns vary from file to file. Some files also have missing columns, and some have extra columns.

I have my master list of column names, and the order in which I would like them all to go. What is the best way to tackle this? LibreOffice gets the CSV parsing right (Excel certainly does not). Ultimately the files will all go into a single merged spreadsheet. Every row from each source file must be kept intact, apart from the column ordering.

The steps also need to be handed over to a non-technical third party eventually, so I am looking for an approach that will not offer too many non-expert technical hurdles.

Comment: I think the I'm leaning towards a PHP application that will merge the CSVs into one, which can then be downloaded as one big CSV. The issues are always going to be parsing the CSV (handling invalid UTF-8, a mix of Unix/DOS line endings between and within records) which LibreOffice deals with so nicely. But I'd rather not go there if there is some simpler solution I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm approaching this problem a different way. I have instead gone back to the source application (WooCommerce) to fix the export, so the spreadsheets list all the same columns and all in the same order, on every export. This does have other consequences that I need to follow up, such as managing patches and trying to get the changes accepted by the source project. But it does avoid having to append the CSV files with mis-matched columns, which seems to be a common issue that no-one has any real solutions for (yes, I have searched, a lot).